# How to get text from text object in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have this Span object as shown in the example. I'm trying to just get the text that says, Au Sable. However, when I use selenium using the XPath and use .text it says unable to get the text because it is a text object.

```xml
<span class="tooltip-row">
   <span>Building: </span>
   Ausable Hall
</span>
```

Can someone help me how I can get the text?

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Selenium does not support XPath queries that return text nodes; only elements can be returned. So your XPath is fine but not usable with Selenium. You could use lxml instead, which will allow you to retrieve the text node. Or you could use Selenium to retrieve both `span` elements (the outer and the inner) and use string manipulation in Python to find the difference between their string values.

Answer (score 1):

Try to navigate to the *span class="tooltip-row"* element and call *getValue()*, not *getText()*.
E.g. pseudocode:

```
 getElement(By.xPath("//span[@class='tooltip-row']").getValue()
```